# Cuál es el error al compilar el código con cout/cin en C++?

Tags: c++, string, punteros

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
 char* name;
 std::cout<<"Ingresa tu nombre: \t";
 std::cin>>name;
 std::cout<<"Tu nombre es: \t"<<name;
 return 0;
}
```

Cuando la variable `name` es de tipo `int`, funciona bien, pero cuando la variable es de tipo `char` para almacenar todo el nombre, al ingresarlo el programa dice que ha dejado de funcionar y ni siquiera alcanza a mostrar el nombre en el último `cout`.

[image: Error al compilar]

Comment: Tu variable no es de tipo `char`, sino que es un puntero a un tipo de dato `char`. Vamos que no es lo mismo `char x` que `char* x`. Por otro lado, como bien señala NaCl, no te compliques la vida y utiliza strings.

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema se debe a que no estás colocando memoria para el puntero `name`.

```
#include<iostream> 
int main() { 
  char* name; //justo aquí
  std::cout<<"Ingresa tu nombre: \t"; 
  std::cin>>name; 
  std::cout<<"Tu nombre es: \t"<<name; 
  return 0;
}
```

Al momento de compilar solo declaras el puntero, pero no asignas memoria para que pueda ser usada en el.

Puedes resolver esto utilizando `malloc` o `calloc` de la librería `stdlib`, si quieres hacerlo de una manera más al estilo de C++, utiliza `std::string` o como te comenta [@eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142733) en su respuesta, puedes utilizar `new` y `delete []`:

Utilizando `stdlib` tu código se vería así:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include <cstdlib> // o stdlib.h
int main() { 
  char* name = (char *)malloc(120);
  std::cout<<"Ingresa tu nombre: \t"; 
  std::cin>>name; 
  std::cout<<"Tu nombre es: \t"<<name; 
  free(name); // libera la memoria pedida.
  return 0;
}
```

En el código anterior, se utiliza la función `malloc` para pedir memoria dinámica, pero ten cuidado, necesitas liberarla al final de su ciclo de vida, de igual forma, sólo he pedido 120 bytes para almacenar información, por lo que si lees más de 120, corromperas el buffer y causará el mismo error que tienes ahora.

De la misma forma, puedes utilizar `std::string` y te ahorras todo el rollo de liberar y colocar la memoria.

```
#include<iostream> 
// #include <cstring> // decomentar si hay error.
int main() { 
  std::string name = ""; //justo aquí
  std::cout<<"Ingresa tu nombre: \t"; 
  std::cin>>name; 
  std::cout<<"Tu nombre es: \t"<<name; 
  return 0;
}
```

Si no necesitas tratar con memoria dinámica, te recomiendo utilizar `std::string` y no utilizar punteros a secas, para todo lo demás, punteros inteligentes y clases de la librería de libcpp.

Saludos :)

Answer (score 2):

El problema ya te lo comenta [@NaCl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142712/463)... solo que ya que estás en C++ te sugiero usar `new[]` y `delete[]` en vez de `malloc` y `free`. Estas últimas funciones son más propias de C que de C++, su sintaxis es más sucia y tienen ciertas limitaciones respecto a las funciones propias de C++:

```
#include<iostream> 

int main() { 
  char* name = new char[100];
  std::cout<<"Ingresa tu nombre: \t"; 
  std::cin>>name; 
  std::cout<<"Tu nombre es: \t"<<name; 
  delete[] name;
  return 0;
}
```

Aunque también podrías evitar el manejo de memoria dinámica si pasas a usar `std::string` (como indica [@NaCl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142712/463)) o `char[]`:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() { 
  char name[100];
  std::cout<<"Ingresa tu nombre: \t"; 
  std::cin>>name; 
  std::cout<<"Tu nombre es: \t"<<name; 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uf!!! Me había olvidado por completo de `new` y `delete`.

Comment: @NaCl mejor... así hay sitio para poner respuestas variadas

Comment: Claro, mientras más opciones funcionales, mejor :P